# Confusion in the proof that the area of the ordinate set of a non-negative function is equal to it's integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

In Apostol Calculus vol.1, the following theorem and proof are given:
[image]

The confusion I have occurs in the part where he mentions:

> Since $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, the number $I=\int_a^bs(x)dx$ is the only number satisfying the inequalities $\int_a^b s(x)dx \le I \le \int_a^b t(x)dx$ for all step functions with $s\le f\le t$. **Therefore, this is also the only number satisfying $a(S)\le I \le a(T)$ for all step regions $S$ and $T$ with $S\subseteq Q \subseteq T$**

Doesn't this conclusion require that going through all the step regions with $S\subseteq Q \subseteq T$ implies going through all step functions with $s\le f\le t$, which I don't think is even true. For example, since, by definition, step regions are the union of finitely many rectanges with their bases resting on the x-axis, for every pair of step functions $s,t$ associated with step regions $S,T$ with $s\subseteq Q\subseteq T$, $ s\ge0 $ and $t\ge 0$, whereas there are clearly step functions with $s<0$ that satisfy $s\le f\le t$. So the set of step functions associated with step regions with $S\subseteq Q \subseteq T$ seems to be a proper subset of the set of step functions with $s\le f\le t$. Isn't it entirely possible, then, that there is a number other than $c=I$ that satisfies $A(S)\le c \le A(T)$ for all step regions $S,T$ with $S\subseteq Q\subseteq T$ ?